# Rails devise sending emails to wrong email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I successfully installed devise in my rails app and the user registration works perfect. I've also set it up such that users can confirm their accounts by sending an email. This works fine when the user  signs up for the first time (They get the confirmation message with a confirmation link).

However, when the user changes his/her email address from `exampleuser@gmail.com` to `exampleuser@hotmail.com`, the mail gets delivered to `exampleuser@gmail.com` and the confirmation link has no confirmation token it looks like

```
http://{HOST}/users/confirmation
```

Instead of the normal

```
http://{HOST}/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=TOKEN_HERE
```

When I resave the new email `exampleuser@hotmail.com` it now gets delivered to this address but the confirmation token is invalid as it does not match the one in the db.

I don't know what went wrong.

**confirmation_instructions.html.erb**

```
<p>Welcome <%= @resource.unconfirmed_email? ? @resource.unconfirmed_email : @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

I also have `config.reconfirmable = true` in devise initializer

Am also using sideqik for delayed jobs. The emails are all processed by sideqik

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realise it is sometime since you posted, but I have run into this same issue and resolved it.

In my case I had upgraded devise from v2.0.4 to v2.2.6 - which appears to be the newest version that supports Rails 3.

I'd skimmed the [change log](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) which mentions this change in v2.2.0:

```
All mailer methods now expect a second argument with delivery options.
```

Unfortunately it doesn't say what that second argument is specifically used for; however it turns out is literally what you'd expect... The options hash that is passed to your Mailers `mail` method.

I'm guessing if you're like me, your previous Devise::Mailer had a line something like the following:

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, opts)
    mail :to => record.email, :template_name => 'confirmation_instructions'
  end
```

The problem is that email is the previous confirmed email address, not the new unconfirmed one.  Hence you probably want to call mail with the options hash you were passed, which will now contain the unconfirmed_email in its `:to` key, e.g.

```
  {:to => "unconfirmed@email.com"}
```

So simply change your mail calls to something more like:

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, opts)
     mail opts.merge(:template_name => 'confirmation_instructions')
  end
```